# Activeadmin custom pages and Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, cancan

I am using Activeadmin and Cancan for user authorization.  It works fine on all standard pages, but on custom pages I am struggling to pass values to Cancan’s Abilities.
On my custom active admin page I have

```
 controller do
   prepend_before_filter :filter_method

   def filter_method
     @project = Project.find(params[:id])
     authorize! :show, @project
   end
 end
```

in Abilities I have

```
 can :manage, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => "Project Preview", :poster_id => user.user_id
```

Now I was hoping that *authorize! :show, @project* would pass the Project values to cancan, but all I am getting is “undefined method `poster_id' “.  I have been playing around with this for hours and am completely stuck so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to override the page controller's `authorize_access!` method; see
the [ActiveAdmin::PageController](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/0becbef0918a38b91ad120aba7c2f6641e9b5440/lib/active_admin/page_controller.rb) 
implementation for reference.

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Project Page with Authorization" do
  content do
    # page content
  end

  controller do
    private

    def find_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    def authorize_access!
      find_project
      authorize! :show, @project
    end
  end
end
```

The ability check would then only be checking against Project and not
ActiveAdmin::Page:

```
can :show, Project, :poster_id => user.user_id
```

Also note that by default the page view is actually the `index` controller
action and is passed the `active_admin_config` as the subject for authorization
checks.